# excel - Worksheet_Change event not triggering

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a block of code that checks if cell C2 has changed and uses it's value as the filter for a column in a pivot table

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xPTable As PivotTable
    Dim xPFile As PivotField
    Dim xStr As String
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C2")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set xPTable = Worksheets("SHARE_CHANGE").PivotTables("PivotTable2")
        Set xPFile = xPTable.PivotFields("category")
        xStr = Target.Text
        xPFile.ClearAllFilters
        xPFile.CurrentPage = xStr
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

to confirm that the event is not firing I added a MsgBox in the beginning and nothing comes up

this is the only vba code in the workbook. macros are not disabled(I made the file). what else could be the reason?

Comment: How is the value in C2 being changed?

Comment: Is this code in the sheet code module? Are events enabled (in the Immediate Window enter `Application.EnableEvents = True` and hit Enter). Does C2 contain a formula?

Comment: @BigBen ok so I closed the file opened it again and now it is working